# Ubuntu crashing with NVidia GeForce 550 Ti

Tags: linux, graphics-card, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an Asus motherboard p8z68-V motherboard with an NVidia GeForce 550 Ti plugged in. The system boots just fine when I'm using the onboard graphics, but when I plug in the GeForce and use that, it won't boot. After I select the OS in GRUB, the screen goes black with a blinking underscore for about 5 seconds, then just goes totally black. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ubuntu?  I ran into this with kernel version 3.0 in Ubuntu 11.10 on one machine, and had to [disable ACPI in the boot options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) to get it to boot (it has an ATI card).  I could (also) boot if I went back to the previous 2.x kernel, but who wants that? ;)

Apparently this is the deal (in my case anyway) until an updated driver is released for kernel v3.

Comment: yep, it's Ubuntu 11.10, the acpi=off flag worked perfectly!!! Thanks a ton man, you're a lifesaver